# Why do non-NULL pointers seemingly convert to NULL when I pass them to a method? (C++)

Tags: c++, methods, printing, null, binary-tree

I have a binary tree that I wish to print. My tree struct is:

```
struct tree
{
  Node * root;
  tree() {root = NULL;}

  Node * insert(Node * n, people * pp);
  void print(Node * pp)
  {  
    if(pp==NULL)
    { cout<<"Node sent to print is null"<<endl; return;}

    print(pp->left);
    cout<<pp->p->lname<<endl;
    print(pp->right);
   }
};
```

In main I call as such:

```
if(tr->root == NULL) cout<<"drat";
  tr -> print(tr->root);
```

I'm fully sure tr->root is not NULL considering I just followed it a line before to print something. Why does my print method insist I'm passing a null value?

Comment: SO is a professional environment. Please don't swear. I've removed the swearing from your question.

Comment: You probably need `Node * insert(Node *& n, people * pp);` but as long you're not showing the implementation there, I can't finally tell.

Comment: You're saying you're seeing `Node sent to print is null` and **not** seeing `drat` before it? I don't see any way that can happen. But the code above absolutely allows for `drat` followed (with no line break) by `Node sent to print is null`, e.g. `dratNode sent to print is null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `print()` function is recursive.  It will go down the tree until it'll find a null leaf and print that message. Then it will print the rest.

I propose following change:

```
 void print(Node * pp)
  {  
    if(pp==NULL)
    { cout<<"Node sent to print is null"<<endl; return;}

    if (pp->left) print(pp->left);
    cout<<pp->p->lname<<endl;
    if (pp->right) print(pp->right);
   }
```